# debugging a 2d linked list system made with classes

Tags: c++, class, pointers, 2d

this might be a long shot, but i need help figuring out why a return statement is sending a null pointer when it should not be. my code is a 2d linked list that can be traversed. but will crash if moved down and then moved up again.
my main class that will call for the next node

```
if((y-dist)>0){ //if not moved out of bounds
    for(int c = 0; c < dist; c++) {//for each step
        node.draw(); //mark current nod as visited
        if(ptr->getup() != NULL){ //another out of bounds check
            ptr = ptr->getup(); //gets the node above it, but returns null
        }
    }
}
```

my node class

```
#ifndef GRIDNODE_H
#define GRIDNODE_H
#include <cstddef>
#include "gridnode.h"
#include "grid.h"
#include "basenode.h"
class gridnode : public basenode{
public:
    gridnode *l, *r, *u, *d;
    gridnode(){
        l = NULL;
        r = NULL;
        u = NULL;
        d = NULL;
    }
    void draw(){mark = pen;}
}
#endinf
```

and the grid that is 50x50 made by quadrupaliy linked lists

```
#include <iostream>
#include "grid.h"
#include "gridnode.h"
#include "basenode.h"
grid::grid(){
gridnode *r1, *r2, *p;
r1 = new gridnode;
head = r1;
for (int i = 2; i <= 50; i++ ){
    r2 = new gridnode;
    r2->l = r1;
    r1->r = r2;
    r1 = r2;
}
r1 = head;
for (int i = 2; i <= 50; i++){
    r2 = new gridnode;
    r2->u = r1;
    r1->d = r2;
    r1 = r2;
    for (int j = 2; j <= 50; j++){
        p = new gridnode;
        p->l = r2;
        r2->r = p;
        p->u = r2->u->r;
        p->u->d = p;
        r2 = p;
    }
}
sethead(head);
}
```

Comment: My debugger's not working at the moment, could you help me?  I need you to run a debugger on your code and post the statement that is causing the issue.  Again, I'd do it, but something is wrong with my debugger.

Comment: I'm guessing you have a local definition of `ptr` that's hiding the one you think you're setting, but you're not showing enough code to know.

Comment: One suggestion -- use descriptive variable names.  You are not charged money for longer, more descriptive names.  Names like "u" and "d" are not helpful, both to you and others looking at the code.